# Confusion about first order tensor transformations

Tags: tensors

So I'm currently learning continuum mechanics and I am a bit confused about my course notes introducing first order transformation rules.

[image]

[image]

[image]
When it says we project $\hat{i}_{i}^{'}$ onto the $\hat{i}_k$, are we writing the new basis vector in terms of the old ones, because if a basis vector is rotated it cannot be a scalar multiple of the original. Or does this give a relationship between the $x$, $y$, and $z$ components of the new basis vector to the original, if so then I'm not sure why the expression before (6.1) appears to be writing a basis vector from the new orthogonal in terms of a basis vector of the original basis?

I'm also confused about the new $k$ and $l$ indices introduced here so I'm hoping someone can clear this up for me, with the level of someone being introduced to tensors for the first time.

Comment: Regarding the source: The horrible person who used $i$ as a vector, its components, and the index for its components is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the expression before ($6.1$) actually yields the new basis vectors' $x$,$y$ and $z$ components in terms of the old ones. Of course, if the vectors were to be defined directly like that, then their modulus wouldn't be $1$, again, like you said. Thus, you can express each of the new rotated basis' vectors like this:
$$\hat i_i'=(\cos\alpha_{i1}\  \cos\alpha_{i2}\ \cos\alpha_{i3})
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat i_1\\
\hat i_2\\
\hat i_3
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Doing it for $i=\{1,2,3\}$, you'd get that the relation between the new rotated basis and the old one would be described via the rotation matrix mentioned in ($6.5$), $C_{ij}$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\hat i_1'\\
\hat i_2'\\
\hat i_3'
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\alpha_{11} & \cos\alpha_{12} & \cos\alpha_{13}\\
\cos\alpha_{21} & \cos\alpha_{22} & \cos\alpha_{23}\\
\cos\alpha_{31} & \cos\alpha_{32} & \cos\alpha_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat i_1\\
\hat i_2\\
\hat i_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13}\\
C_{21} & C_{22} & C_{23}\\
C_{31} & C_{32} & C_{33}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat i_1\\
\hat i_2\\
\hat i_3
\end{pmatrix}$$

As to the meaning of the $k$ and $l$ indices, they're associated to each basis (old and new, respectively) and they account for all possible angles/vectors. If not, the Kronecker delta $\delta_ {ik}$ and $\delta_{jl}$ would always be $0$, and so, you wouldn't be able to prove the last equality. Other than that they don't mean much more.

Comment: Thanks for clear up. For the repeated indices as stated, would it also mean that expression 6.3 would have nine total terms? (for the repeated k's and i's)

Comment: Correct, the repeated index $i$ is summed over when multipliplying both $C$ matrices (definition of matrix product) so the only variable indices are $j$ and $k$. This way, $\cos(\alpha_{ji})\cos(\alpha_{ki})=\delta_{jk}$ is a $3\times 3$ identity matrix with its dimensions as a consequence of $j$ and $k$'s cardinality. So yes, $9$ total terms.